# Avoiding do_shortcode() loops

Tags: theme-development, themes, shortcode

I have a situation with a custom theme I'm developing that creates custom widgets made to accept shortcode. Issues arise though when that shortcode evokes shortcode of its own. The potential arises for a shortcode output to contain its own shortcode call, which has in test environments caused an infinite loop that times out any page evoking it.

Is there any way to nip this on the bud? How would I go about executing shortcode while disabling any shortcodes nested inside. I tried passing 'true' as the $ignore_html argument, but to no avail.

Comment: If there's an infinite loop problem with shortcodes then the problem is with the code of the shortcode, not a widget or template that executes shortcodes. I'm not sure this is your problem to solve. Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do?

Comment: Did you create these shortcodes yourself? If so, perhaps if you can share the code to create the shortcodes and an example of a loop that timed out, perhaps we can assist better.

Comment: you should break that infinite loop, can you provide an example? a shortcode should only be calling `do_shortcode` on its content, it shouldn't be doing it as a shorthand for implementing other things. Without examples that can be worked with it's difficult to answer this, potentially impossible as any answer has to be theoretical. Additionally, you never told us what the original problem that these widgets were trying to solve, you instead asked about a problem with your solution, maybe if you asked about the original problem there'd be a much better more reliable solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not made the shortcodes in question myself. They're provided by a 3rd party plugin. However, the error can be reproduced easily enough.

1) Download Content Blocks (Custom Post Widget) or similar plugin.
2) Create a new content block, it will give you shortcode to evoke it.
3) Insert that shortcode into the block's content.
4) Place the shortcode into a text widget or post.

Comment: All I'm doing in my code is throwing the shortcode input by the user into a do_shortcode('variable') call and echoing it out, but to avoid the situation I'm looking for a way on my end to examine the shortcode's return content before any potential nested shortcode is parsed. That way I could check for duplicates and extract them.

Comment: Wait, hang on. Are you trying to insert a content block's shortcode into itself? Of course that will cause an infinite loop. But this is user error. Or maybe the content blocks plugin should be updated to prevent this. Either way it's not your problem to solve with your widget or template.

Comment: Indeed, and I'm well aware of that. Obviously in a real world situation, nobody would intentionally want a post to infinitely repeat itself, and causing this situation is indeed user error. I've already notified the plugin's authors of the issue, as it certainly does lie within the plugin itself.

However, though not technically my problem to solve, I'm looking for any way I could mitigate it on the widget and/or template side.